# Tcl / Tk binding won't be executed

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I just started to learn tcl and it might be relevant that I'm using python's tkinter interpreter. But it should be the same, as far as I can tell.

However, I'm using pretty much the same code from the [tcler's wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Bindings+and+variable+substitution) but the bounded procedure never gets executed. The toplevel is created and responsive, but moving or resize the window which is parsed to `$win` will not trigger the `<Configure>` event. It does not fail with an error the procedure just never gets called. Could be something obvious, but I just don't see it.

```
namespace eval MyTk {
    variable TracedWindows {}
    proc StickTo {win w h x y} {
        wm geometry $win.sub $wx$h+$x+$y
    }
    proc TraceWindow {win {value true}} {
        set name $win
        if {$win == "."} {set name ""}
        if {$value && $win ni $MyTk::TracedWindows} {
            toplevel $name.sub
            bind $win <Configure> {$MyTk::StickTo %W %w %h %X %Y}
        }
    }
}
```

---

update, the following works. So it has to do with my namespace or how I address it:

```
bind $win <Configure> {bell}
```

Comment: try this : `bind $win <Configure> [list MyTk::StickTo %W %w %h %X %Y]`

Comment: @Mkn unfortunately it doesn't work, I already tried something similar with curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I found out that if you fail, for whatever reason, in your bounded procedure you won't get an error and it just don't work. Coming from python this is a bit surprising but now that I know, I can deal with it.

I used this code BTW:

```
bind $win <Configure> {::MyTk::StickTo %W}
```

and:

```
proc StickTo {widget} {
    set name $widget
    if {$widget == "."} {set name ""}
    wm geometry $name.sub [wm geometry $widget]
```

I used the command `bell` in the `proc` and added line by line to make it work. One needs to code tcl with greater care as it seems.

Comment: That sounds like a missing `bgerror` implementation (which handles all errors that bubble out of the top of an event callback). The fallback default just prints to what it thinks is the console (wherever the Tcl `stderr` channel goes to). *However,* Tk is supposed to supply it's own that pops up a dialog box; it's in a lazily sourced file and defining your own will stop that. Don't know why that isn't working (too many possibilities)...

Comment: @DonalFellows could you elaborate on it a bit more ? Or point me to anything for further reading ? As far as I can tell tkinter implements [`TclError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L39)  and `Exception` in line 50. Another thing I can see is [`tkerror`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2356) and in the C-implementation there is [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c#L318) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1476) should apply, since I used eval.

Comment: As I said, I suspect that something is swallowing `stderr`, making the fallback silent. It's a bit hard to say why. But you can always define your own. The standard one by Tk is at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=library/bgerror.tcl&ci=tip (mirrored at https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/bgerror.tcl)